# Черз Qprocess вызвать 7za.exe и передать ей строку с параметрами

Tags: c++, qt

```
void Widget::on_pushButtonCmd_clicked()
 {
    QProcess *cmd=new QProcess(this);
    QString programm = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
    QStringList arguments;
   arguments <<"C:\\7za.exe"
          <<"-u"
          <<"-tzip"
          <<"-x!*.zip"
          <<"D:\\TESTZIP\\backup.zip"
          <<"D:\\TESTZIP\\1.txt";
cmd->start(programm);
cmd->waitForStarted();
cmd->setArguments(arguments);
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста. Через Qprocess  вызываю консоль. В консоли вызываю консольную версию 7za.exe с ключами. Но программа висит и архив не создается.

Answer (score 5):

Код:

```
QString programm = "C:\\7za.exe";  // Путь правильный?
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "u"  // !!!
          << "-tzip"
          << "-x!*.zip"
          << "C:\\New/backup.zip"
          << "C:\\New/1.txt";

QProcess *cmd = new QProcess(this);
cmd->start(programm, arguments);
```

1. Почему бы не запустить архиватор, передав путь в QProcess?
2. Ключ для архиватора пишется без дефиса "u" (см. документацию)

Comment: Описание ключей команды 7z. Общий синтаксис:

7z <команда> <ключи> <архивный файл> <объект архивирования>

Comment: u  - это команда. Обновление файлов в архиве. Если файла нет, создает новый.

Comment: Путь правильный. Если сам пишу в консоли все пути - архив создается. Если в качестве аргументов передаю - нет. Увы. Опыта очень мало.

Comment: @ВасилийАлибабаевич мой пример не работает у тебя?

Comment: Я затупил. Твой пример работает. Спасибо тебе огромное. Разобрался!